# NekoHtml with multiple values in a attribute

Tags: java, html, xml

I have a problem with NekoHTML 
I try to parse the HTML pages, where Some eventually tags have attributes of type class. These attributes must have multiple values​​, such as class = 'ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable' The problem is that using NekoHtml, is extracted only the first value of the class and then: class = 'ui-dialog'

The code I use is as follows, but I can not understand why this behavior, and if I can change it.

```
    URL newURL = new URL(url);
    Reader source = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(newURL.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
    doc = parseHTML(source);
```

**EDIT**

```
public Document parseHTML(Reader in) throws SAXException, IOException {
    DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
    parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
    parser.setFeature("http://cyberneko.org/html/features/balance-tags", true);
    XMLDocumentFilter[] filters = { new Purifier() };
    parser.setProperty("http://cyberneko.org/html/properties/filters", filters);
    parser.parse(new InputSource(in));
    return parser.getDocument();
}
```

an example of page is http://www.123premier.com/used-cars/2257/hyundai-matrix/#

the using the xpath expression //A[@class='addthis_button_facebook at300b'] it doesn't find anything. But if i use the firebugs in firefox it give me the correct node.
the code for the xpath expression is the following

```
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    DTMNodeList result = (DTMNodeList) xPath.evaluate("//A[@class='addthis_button_facebook at300b']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I use NekoHTML for reading the attributes but I haven't observed such behavior. How do you actually read the attribute value? What is inside the parseHTML() function? And do you have any example of the HTML code?

Comment: thank you @radkovo for the comment. Now i have edited the post with the others information ;-)

Comment: I have done some experiments but it seems that removing the class names is a specific behavior that occurs with the mentioned document only. If you copy the corresponding part of the code to a new document, it works correctly (at300b class is not removed). It could be even a bug in the parser -  I would recommend to contact the authors directly.